# How to inherite a custom form (visual inheritance) from delphi Dll in my delphi project

Tags: delphi, inheritance, plugins, dll, delphi-xe3

I have a dll (Created in Delphi) which includes a TGlobalForm inherited from TForm

I want to use the TGlobalForm in my project (Delphi Project) and inherit some forms from TGlobalForm.

Example 
   TAccountsForm = class(TGlobalForm)

the problem is that I don't want to use the GlobalForm pas file in the Uses of the project
and I want it to be like when you create a new form (File->New->Other) and you choose the (inheritable Items) under (Delphi Projects) Node so the new created form will show items (Buttons, Edits...) of the inherited form (TGlobalForm)

how to accomplish this?

I'm using Delphi XE3 - VCL Project

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to import and use a VCL object from a DLL. When you try to do so you end up with two different instances of the VCL, including two different distinct versions of the imported form type. There's the version in the DLL, and the version in the application. They are distinct, and two versions of the type is one too many.

The supported way to import a complex type from another module is to use a package. If you don't want to use packages, then you'll have to use some form of interop that does work across DLL module boundaries. For example, COM interfaces.

Comment: He suggests that he has the GlobalForm.pas file itself in the question, though. Not sure what DLLs have to do with it in that case, though

Comment: @Matt That's the source file for the form. It's compiled into the DLL. He wants to avoid compiling it into the app as well. But that's not possible. Packages are what's needed to put VCL objects in different modules.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can you please provide any example for that using Packages? if it is hard please give me more details or links on how to reach visual inheritance using Delphi packages.

Comment: What I need is to have something similar to plugins and the designer of the plugin must use my dll to inherit visual forms from my global forms.

Comment: for example all of my forms must have my own custom database navigator and my own custom database grid and they all have special design only the form function is different and of course the user must be able to add more buttons and objects.